# Связь Многие-ко-многим, передача данных в контроллер и представление ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте.

Есть 2 таблицы `SepticTank` и `Discount`.
Как передать все данные в контроллер и представление при связи многие-ко-многим, если на некоторых моделях есть скидка, а на других нет?

вот пример кода:

Модель SepticTank.cs

```
public class SepticTank
{
    [Display(Name = "Наименование модели")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Модель")]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 20000000, ErrorMessage = "Недопустимая цена")]
    [Display(Name = "1 компрессор")]
    public int Cost1Comp { get; set; }    //Цена с 1 компрессором
    [Range(0, 20000000, ErrorMessage = "Недопустимая цена")]
    [Display(Name = "2 компресора")]
    public int Cost2Comp { get; set; }    //Цена с 2 компрессорами
    [Range(1, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Недопустимое количество пользователей")]
    [Display(Name = "Количество пользователей")]
    public int CountUsers { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 500, ErrorMessage = "Недопустимый дневной приток")]
    [Display(Name = "Максимальный дневной приток")]
    public double InflowDrain { get; set; }  //Максимальный дневной приток
    [Range(0, 300, ErrorMessage = "Недопустимая число использования электроэнергии")]
    [Display(Name = "Энергия")]
    public double Energy { get; set; }
    [Range(1, 200, ErrorMessage = "Недопустимая длина")]
    [Display(Name = "Длина")]
    public double Lenght { get; set; }
    [Range(1, 200, ErrorMessage = "Недопустимая ширина")]
    [Display(Name = "Ширина")]
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    [Range(1, 200, ErrorMessage = "Недопустимая высота")]
    [Display(Name = "Высота")]
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Discount> Discounts { get; set; }

    public SepticTank()
    {

        Discounts = new List<Discount>();
    }
```

Модель Discount.cs:

```
public class Discount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Дата начала акции")]
    public DateTime DateBegin { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Дата окончания акции")]
    public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "Недопустимый процент")]
    [Display(Name = "Процент скидки")]
    public int Percent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SepticTank> SepticTanks { get; set; }

    public Discount()
    {
        SepticTanks = new List<SepticTank>();
    }
}
```

Модель SepticTankContext.cs

```
 public class SepticTankContext : DbContext
{
    public SepticTankContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }
    public DbSet<SepticTank> SepticTanks { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Discount> Discounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Discount>().HasMany(c => c.SepticTanks)
            .WithMany(s => s.Discounts)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("DiscountId")
            .MapRightKey("SepticTankId")
            .ToTable("DiscountSepticTank"));
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

В проекте можно вывести все данные, но на странице будут показываться только те записи из первой таблицы, которые уже связаны со второй

вот пример действия в контроллере

```
public ActionResult Models()
    {
        SepticTank Sept = db.SepticTanks.Find();
        ViewBag.Discounts = db.Discounts.ToList();
        return View(Sept);
    }
```

а также вот примерное представление Models.cshtml

```html
@using ProjectTopas_v_1._2.Models
@model SepticTank
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Модельный ряд";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Модель</th>
                <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><p>Цена, руб.</p></th>
                <th rowspan="2">Количество <br />пользователей, чел.</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Максимально дневной<br /> приток, м<sup>3</sup>/сутки</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Энергия,<br />Квт/сутки</th>
                <th colspan="3" style="text-align:center">Габаритные размеры</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>1 компрессор</th>
                <th>2 компрессора</th>
                <th>Длина, м</th>
                <th>Ширина, м</th>
                <th>Высота, м</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var b in Model.Discounts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><a href="/Home/Details/@Model.Id">@Model.Model</a></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center">
                        <p>
            @if (Model.Cost1Comp == 0)
            { }
            else
            {
                double d = Math.Round(Model.Cost1Comp * (1 - ((double)b.Percent / 100)));
                <small><s style="color:gray">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cost1Comp)</s></small>
                      <p style="color:red">@d (-@b.Percent %)</p>
    }
                        
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:center">
                        <p>
            @if (Model.Cost2Comp == 0)
            { }
            else
            {
                double d = Math.Round(Model.Cost2Comp * (1 - ((double)b.Percent / 100)));
                <small><s style="color:gray">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cost2Comp)</s></small>
                     <p style="color:red">@d (-@b.Percent %)</p>
                  }
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><p>@Model.CountUsers</p></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><p>@Model.InflowDrain</p></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><p>@Model.Energy</p></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><p>@Model.Lenght</p></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><p>@Model.Weight</p></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><p>@Model.Height</p></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Связь многие ко многим говорит о неправильном проектировании БД.

Comment: Извините, но что вам будет удобнее: каждый раз записывать дату и процент скидки на одну модель, или однажды записать дату и процент на несколько моделей?

Comment: для меня структуру данных определяет erd модель данных, а не понятие модели в asp.net которую можно заполнить множеством способов. и структура должна исполняться в минимум 3 нормальной форме. как правило связь многие ко многим исчезает в этом случаев. Знаю людей кому удобно в 1 таблице всю кашу данных хранить, не в удобствах дело, а в многолетних доказанных нормах хранения информации. А как заполнять свойства в классе это уже дело второстепенное.

Comment: Я понимаю, просто не знаю как нормально реализовать таблицу со скидками, поэтому эта таблица была последней что я добавил в БД, к тому же на эту таблицу работает триггер, который удаляет записи, в которых дата окончания скидки совпадает или превысило системное время